# How to migrate a rails app from engineyard to Google appengine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, jruby

I have a RoR 2.3.8 application running on EC2, I am using engineyard. which is prooved to be significantly costly to me. I want to migrate to GAE.

Can anyone please tell me the steps and points i suppose to remember while doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [appengine-jruby](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/) project or an another way is to use [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Currently GAE doesn't support Ruby. It only supports Java and Python. Check the link for more info [languages supported by GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#language).

But i believe , if you convert your rails app to JRuby, then you can run  it in GAE. Because JRuby runs on JVM. I have read the articles long before how to run JRuby apps in GAE. you can google it.

Answer (score 1):

GAE supports only Python and Java. OK there was Go! added recently. So, Rubby is not on the list unfortunately.